# Google Cloud SQL backups are not running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have a Cloud SQL database and have set up backups following the steps at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery.

As can be seen in the screenshot below, no backup showing in Google developer console.

[image]

Why is no backup running and how do we make sure backups run as scheduled?

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud SQL will skip doing a backup if it knows that no backup is needed. This will be the case if the instance was idle since the last backup.

Try connecting to you instance and having some activity, and see if a backup runs in the next 24 hours.